# first item on recyclerview stacked up to tab layout

Tags: android

[image: first item on recyclerview stacked up to tab layout]

i already check the xml file, but everything is okay (for me), but the view still stacked up. and i also get an error message like this

> PlayingFragment: onResponse: hasil
>   pemanggilanretrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@1c95dee5

and here's what inside on onResponse on my PlayingFramgment class

```
private void bacaData(){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final RecyclerView rvCategory = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.playing_daftar);
        rvCategory.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit(getContext()).create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<MovieResponse> call = apiInterface.getNowPlaying();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                MovieResponse data = response.body();
                if (data.getResults().size() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Maaf data yang anda cari tidak ditemukan",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    rvCategory.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(data.getResults(), R.layout.list_movie_row, getContext()));
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: hasil pemanggil" + call);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

i post the xml layout fragment_playing

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragment.PlayingFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/playing_daftar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressMainBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_playing is the part of fragment_home, and here's the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and i put the fragment_home into content_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

content_main is the part of app_bar_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/tabs">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tab_np"
                android:text="@string/now_playing"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/up_coming"
                android:id="@+id/tab_up"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the xml...

Comment: @mTak done. i already post the xml codes

Comment: This alone is not useful. You need to post the activity's xml where the problem is

Comment: hey @mTak i already put another xml code

Comment: app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" this working with android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using RelativeLayout as root component you have to give margin top to  RecyclerView:

```
android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
```

**EDIT:**

if you were using coordinatorLayout as Root layout, the story would be different.

***EDIT***

Following issues are obvious in your codes:

1- AppBarLayout in Fragment home is extra since you have already an Appbar in activitie's home layout.

2- According to android official document use CoordinatorLayout instead of RelativeLayout. By using RelativeLayout you will loose some functionality and layout management of AppBarLayout

3- Since you have just included content_main inside app_bar_main, no needs to use `tools:context=".MainActivity"` and `tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"`

4- Replace RelativeLayout inside content_main by merge tag

After above changes you have just removed extra layouts which may have side effects on margins and padings, then apply attribute below to your view pager. I hope these changes will be effective and no other hidden items are alive in your code:

```
android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
```

Comment: I checked your question more decisively, You have written it too messy and try to make it tidy. I'm trying to make it tidy and post you with an answer below this question.

Comment: Consider Edit 2 :) please aware me from result

Answer (score 0):

You should use `below` property so your viewPager below your upper tab. I think your viewPager have height and width both are match parent.

Comment: does your viewPager is below on tab? or can you please post your viewPager xml?

Answer (score 0):

change you Relativelayout to android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout and add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to  android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..
make viewpager xml code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tab_bg_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlConversation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_color"
        app:tabMinWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Tab_Style"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_color"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text_color">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

after that fragement xml code for recyclerview ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rvData"
    tool:listitem="@layout/item_row_layout"
    ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvEmpty"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tool:text="No data found"
    android:text="@string/no_found"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

after that setup view pager like this way make viewpager adapter..

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),conversationId);
  
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItem);
}
```

And

```
  public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
      private final Context context;

      public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context) {
          super(fragmentManager);
          this.context = context;
      }
  
      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          if(position == 0) return new ActiveConversationFragment();
          if(position == 1) return new InvitedConversationFragment();
          if(position == 2) return new RecentConversationFragment();

          throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
      }
  
      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return 3;
      }
  
      @Override
      public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
          if(position == 0) return context.getString(R.string.tab_active_conversation_title);
          if(position == 1) return getString(R.string.tab_invited_conversation_title);
          if(position == 2) return getString(R.string.tab_recent_conversation_title);
        
          throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected position " + position);
      }
  }
```

after that call above method like this way set into tablayout..

```
  setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for app_mar_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:id="@+id/tabs">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tab_np"
                android:text="@string/now_playing"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/up_coming"
                android:id="@+id/tab_up"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```